# Autofac OnActivated not working / calling

Tags: inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm trying to use Autofac OnActivated to create a class

Along the lines of

```
builder.Register(c => new MyThing(c.Resolve<MyOtherThingDependancy>()))
    .As<IMyThing>()
    .SingleInstance()
    .OnActivated(c=> new MyOtherThing(c.Instance)); // i only need this to be instantiated once
```

MyOtherThing has a ctor like:

```
public MyOtherThing(IMyThing myThing)
```

However, it's not firing

`MyOtherThing` never gets instantiated

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why your `OnActivated` isn't happening, but you could do this instead:

```
builder.Register(c => new MyThing(c.Resolve<MyOtherThingDependancy>()))
    .As<IMyThing>()
    .SingleInstance()

builder.RegisterType<MyOtherThing>().AutoActivate();
```

I think using  `AutoActivate` has clearer intent then your style.

Comment: I wasn't aware of AutoActivate.... I haven't read the docs on it, but already I agree, lot clearer intent!